# Does the algebraic group E8 ever "collate" two sets of copies of the algebraic group E6?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Background:

If you look at my recent question here:

[Does a 4_21 exist with 4 vertices from each of of 24 1_22's and 6 from each of 24 "octadeca-diminished" 1_22's (all 48 mutually disjoint)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528109/does-a-4-21-exist-with-4-vertices-from-each-of-of-24-1-22s-and-6-from-each-of-2)

you will see that this question is one possible narrow formulation of a more general question.

More General Question:

Does the algebraic group E8 ever "collate" two sets of copies of the algebraic group E6?

If anyone can think of a known case in which E8 does act in this fashion, I would be grateful to know of it.

Thank you for whatever time you can afford to spend considering this matter.